# Is there a comprehensive list of registered BIP43 purposes?

Tags: bip44

Where can I find a comprehensive list of all proposed and/or used "purposes" as defined in [BIP43](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0043.mediawiki)?

So far I could only find these:

- 44: [BIP-0044](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki): Multi-Account Hierarchy for Deterministic Wallets
- 45: [BIP-0045](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0045.mediawiki): Structure for Deterministic P2SH Multisignature Wallets
- 48: [SLIP-0048](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/issues/49): Deterministic Key Hierarchy for Graphene-based Networks
- 80: [BIP-0080](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0080.mediawiki): Hierarchy for Non-Colored Voting Pool Deterministic Multisig Wallets

Is there a comprehensive list? or does anybody know of any other that I could add to this list?

Comment: Same question here. Regarding BIP 44, I found a list of coin types in [SLIP44](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md)

Comment: GPG/SSH support uses `m/0x80'GPG'`, aka `m/80475047` according to [Ledger's application](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-app-openpgp-card/blob/master/doc/developper/gpgcard3.0-addon.rst#deterministic-key-derivation)

Comment: Well since I made this question, I just found a couple more 'purpose' definitions. These are purpose 49 and 84, defined in [BIP-49](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki) and [BIP-84](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0084.mediawiki) respectively. These describe different derivation purposes, used to derive different keys for the 2 different ways of creating segwit addresses.

Comment: 43 and the range 10001–19999 are potentially reserved (see https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/523). EIP600 already builds on the purpose 43 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-600).

Comment: 13 is used in SLIP13 (https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0013.md)

Comment: Note: the GPG path component is 0x80'GPG' aka. 0x80475047 (hex!) aka. 2152157255 where the 0x80 only sets the high bit for the purpose. The purpose is 4673607 (2152157255 XOR 0x80000000).